# Install GUI on Ubuntu server 14.04 Trusty Tahr - VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, gui

When I had installed a GUI in Ubuntu Server (In virtualbox) with

```
sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

I had a problem: the screen gets in black, and only appear the cursor.

Comment: A better question is what makes you think you need a GUI on a server ? Use a web based tool to manage your server.

Comment: That was certainly not a better question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install the corresponding metapackage `gnome` (should be the same as `gnome-desktop-environment`) instead of single other packages. Probably you're missing a dependency.

I recommend the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want the full environment with all additional programs you might not necessarily need, you can also just install the core desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```